# How to resize images already uploaded on firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm stuck in resizing images on firebase storage.
I know the way to resize and make thumbnail when users upload images.
However, I like to know images already uploaded on firebase storage.
Because images are already uploaded on our server and I really need to resize those images.
Image size is big, so component render is really slow.
If you have any tips, please let me know with your code.
Thank you.

Comment: You can create a cloud function that create a smaller version each time you upload or for all existing images

Comment: You're going to have to write some code to identify all the images in storage that need to be resized, download each one, resize it, then upload it back.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I know but how? cause I don't have File but url that I could get it using 'getDownloadUrl' from firebase storage.

Comment: A full description is too long for Stack Overflow.  You have a series of tasks that you can research and implement individually.  If you're having problem coding any one of them, please post a new question to share the code, what it's supposed to do, and how it doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a simple solution.
However, there was a simple way.
I had to download all of the images, resized and upload them.
I used GCE for this and if you use `gsutil`, you could simply do this.
Create instance on google cloud platform to perform this process.
I talked to google cloud platform team, cloud function is not a good idea for this because it might cause some issues.
when you are all set, start with this command.

`gsutil cp -r gs://my-bucket/data [path where you want to download]`

and to resize images I used `sharp`.
after resize all of images, you simply upload like this.

`gsutil cp -r [path your images] gs://my-bucket/data`

That's all.

Comment: You deserve a medal. I think this is the easiest solution to resize existing images. I downloaded a software to resize (Easy Thumbnails) and rename the files, did the resizing, then uploaded in a new thumbnails folder.